# dockers - flask python errors

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am trying to use docker to creating an image for my flask app program deployment. i think i have successfully created the docker file as follows:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

RUN adduser -D microblog

WORKDIR /Users/pangkachun/Desktop/New_Blog

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m venv venv
RUN venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN venv/bin/pip install gunicorn

COPY app app
COPY migrations migrations
COPY microblog.py config.py boot.sh ./
RUN chmod +x boot.sh

ENV FLASK_APP microblog.py

RUN chown -R microblog:microblog ./
USER microblog

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["./boot.sh"]
```

and boot.sh as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
source venv/bin/activate
flask db upgrade

exec gunicorn -b :5000 --access-logfile - --error-logfile - microblog:app
```

However, the below errors occurred:

"""
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-n8a9ohsg/cffi/
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
"""

I have checked my pip and cffi and they are already the most updated. Some people said it is because some of my project dependencies are C dependant, but i dun have the c compiler. my requirements.txt is as below

```
alembic==1.0.0
amqp==2.2.2
anyjson==0.3.3
Babel==2.6.0
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
billiard==3.5.0.3
blinker==1.4
celery==4.1.0
certifi==2018.4.16
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
DateTime==4.2
Django==2.0.3
django-adaptors==0.2.5
django-bootstrap3==10.0.1
django-braces==1.13.0
django-celery==3.2.2
django-celery-results==1.0.1
dominate==2.3.4
elasticsearch==6.3.1
fake-useragent==0.1.10
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-Babel==0.11.2
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
Flask-HTTPAuth==3.2.4
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Migrate==2.2.1
Flask-Moment==0.6.0
Flask-SocketIO==3.0.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
guess-language-spirit==0.5.3
gunicorn==19.9.0
httpie==1.0.0
idna==2.6
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.9.6
kombu==4.1.0
lxml==4.1.1
Mako==1.0.7
MarkupSafe==1.0
misaka==2.1.0
numpy==1.13.1
opencv-python==3.2.0.8
pandas==0.22.0
pycparser==2.18
Pygments==2.2.0
PyJWT==1.6.4
python-dateutil==2.6.1
python-dotenv==0.9.1
python-editor==1.0.3
python-engineio==2.3.2
python-socketio==2.0.0
pytz==2018.3
redis==2.10.6
requests==2.18.4
rq==0.12.0
selenium==3.12.0
six==1.11.0
SQLAlchemy==1.2.12
urllib3==1.22
vine==1.1.4
virtualenv==15.1.0
visitor==0.1.3
Werkzeug==0.12.2
WTForms==2.2.1
yandex.translate==0.3.5
zope.interface==4.4.3
```

anyone can advise what is the problems? Thanks a lot !

Comment: What is the version of pip? pip --version

Comment: my version is pip 18.1

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message looks self explanatory. Just upgrade the `pip` inside your `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
```

or

```
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

In most distros of Python pip is not the latest and requires manual upgrade, while I dont see `pip` upgrade code in your `Dockerfile`

Also try installing `gcc` - some Python packages require compilation and alpine-python goes without `gcc` by default.

```
RUN apk add -y gcc
```

Comment: Thanks it solves part of the error. However, the error msg "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-4k833t_u/cffi/" still here. any insight

Comment: Edited answer - try installing gcc.